# Style parent if child contains X

Tags: css, parent-child

I was wondering if there is a **CSS-only** way of styling an element based on it's child?

In my present situation, i've got an `ul` with a lot of `li`'s in it. None of them have a separate identifying class, but only one of them got an iFrame (youtube video) inside of it. That `li` item, I want to style.

The CSS would somewhat be like

```
ul li:child-is[iframe] {
    // styling
}
```

Is this possible?

Comment: With pure CSS it is not possible as on today because there is no parent selector. You may have to use JS/jQuery.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not today.

In the next occurrence of CSS, CSS4, [you'll be able to precise the **subject** in a selector](http://css4-selectors.com/selector/css4/subject-of-selector-with-child-combinator/) using an exclamation mark :

```
ul !li iframe { 
    // styling applies to the li element
}
```

but there's no pure CSS solution **today**.

Comment: I already was afraid of that. Thanks!

Comment: @SanderSchaeffer But rejoice : the future is brighter